# Suppress linker warning for 3rd party framework

Tags: objective-c, xcode, clang, warnings, ld

The Microsoft SDK for Azure Storage causes a bunch of linker errors a la

```
ld: warning: instance method 'AZSULLRangeValue' in category from /Users/macHack/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECT-gpihzjouhxvifqcslmywktktizer/Build/Intermediates.noindex/AZSClient.build/Debug/AZS_Mac.build/Objects-normal-asan-ubsan/x86_64/AZSCloudAppendBlob.o conflicts with same method from another category
```

Is there a way to suppress just the `conflicts with same method from another category` linker warning?

It's easy to find a list of flags for each ***clang*** warning to turn it off on a per-file basis, however I was unable to locate a similar list for ***linker*** warnings?

Obviously the idea is to disable the warning as specifically and as locally as possible and retain other warnings for the project.
Any hints appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you are not accidentally importing a .m file somewhere?

Comment: @skaak Well.. it's an error within the 3rd party project presumably due to doubly defined debugging categories. Xcode validation doesn't come up with anything fishy for this project.

Comment: Ok ... or maybe something gets included or linked twice somewhere ...